# How to access files in data folder in zend framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

currently i am working on zf2. Right now i have to give download option to download pdf files.i have stored all the pdf files in `data` directory.How can i specify link to that pdf files from .phtml file?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please see my updated answer, a 1:1 implementation of my previous code has a huge security risk ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) in public directory for PDF files in data folder.

For example:

```
ln -s /your/project/data/pdfdir /your/project/public/pdf
```

and create links something like

```
<a href="/pdf/file.pdf">File.pdf</a>
```

Answer (score 7):

A user will never gain direct access to your `/data` directory. This would be just not that good. But you can easily write yourself a `download-script.php` or the likes that will hand out the content of this directory to your users.

If you take a look at the first six lines of `public/index.php` you'll see the following:

```
<?php
/**
 * This makes our life easier when dealing with paths. Everything is relative
 * to the application root now.
 */
chdir(dirname(__DIR__));
```

With this in mind, you know that **from PHP's side of things** the access to anything inside the `data` directory is as simple as `data/file.pdf`

You'd always want to write yourself some sort of download-logger. Write yourself a controller. Have an action inside of that controller probably called something like `download` or anything like that. That action should have one parameter `filename`.

All that this action does is to check if filename exists `file_exists('data/'.$filename)` and if it exists, you simply deliver this file to your users. An example mix or zf2 and native php could be:

```
public function downloadAction() 
{
    $filename = str_replace('..', '', $this->params('filename'));
    $file     = 'data/' . $filename;

    if (false === file_exists($file)) {
        return $this->redirect('routename-file-does-not-exist');
    }

    $filetype = finfo_file($file);
    header("Content-Type: {$filetype}");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$filename}\"");
    readfile($file);

    // Do some DB or File-Increment on filename download counter
    exit();
}
```

**This is not clean ZF2** but i'm lazy right now. It may be much much more ideal to use a proper `Response` Object and do the File-Handling there!

**Important Update** this thing was actually quite insecure, too. You need to disallow parent-folders. You wouldn't wanna have this guy do something outside of the `data/download`  directory like

```
`http://domain.com/download/../config/autoload/db.local.php`
```

If I'm not totally mistaken, simply replacing all occurences of double-dots should be enough...

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing Sam's code, here's what it looks like in ZF2 syntax.

```
public function downloadAction()
{
    $filename = str_replace('..', '', $this->params('filename'));
    $file     = 'data/' . $filename;

    if (false === file_exists($file)) {
        return $this->redirect('routename-file-does-not-exist');
    }

    $filetype = finfo_file($file);
    $response = new \Zend\Http\Response\Stream();
    $response->getHeaders()->addHeaders(array(
        'Content-Type' => $filetype,
        'Content-Disposition' => "attachement; filename=\"$filename\""
    ));
    $response->setStream(fopen($wpFilePath, 'r'));
    return $response;
}
```